# less x.deb - what's wrong with it?

Tags: less

I've tried to strace a program and send the strace's output to a file x.deb.
After opening x.deb I've seen this:

```
x.deb:

*** Contents:
x.deb (END)
```

I thought it is a bug in strace, because if I used x.x instead of x.deb, then the result was correct. But (I don't know why) when I opened x.deb with a cat, then it shown the actual content of the file, so... if it is a bug, then the bug is in the less, not in strace.
But I'm not sure if it is a bug, because I've tried it with more versions of command less with the same result.
What is it? Could you help me?

Comment: Tried versions off less: 481 on Ubuntu 16.04, 487 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the file ends with .deb so the less command thinks that the file is a Debian package and tries to provide an unpacked view of the package. However, the data you are providing is just plain ASCII output from strace and not a Debian package so the less command can't unpack it.

If you use another filename without the .deb suffix it will work OK.